# script to replace text where replacing sting follow caption pattern of old

Tags: python, regex, bash, shell

I need help in writing a script that will replace given text string with new one from all the files in a directory structure.
The condition is new string must also follow caption patters of old string.

For e.g.
if I want to replace "abc" with "xyz" in a project. It must also search and replace following patterns
"ABC" by "XYZ" 
"Abc" by "Xyz"
"AbC" by "XyZ"
.. and so on.

Can some one suggest optimized logic for this?

Comment: Is there **only** `A or a`, `B or b`, `C or c` ?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Python regex or Bash?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far, For the logic you can use regular expression

Answer (score 0):

import re

string = "xYZ"

d = { 'X':'A' , 'Y':'B', 'Z':'C'}

for c in string:

```
if c.isupper():

    string = re.sub(c,d[c],string)

else:

    string = re.sub(c,d[c.upper()].lower(),string)
```

print string